# Start navigation automatically with Google Maps and Apple Maps URL Schemes

Tags: ios, google-maps, url-scheme, apple-maps

Is there a way to start navigation automatically when launching [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme) or [Apple Maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) with a URL Scheme on iOS?

I see several optional parameters for both but none to start navigation without user input.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I did it for your reference, but for apple, I haven't found a way to start the navigation through url scheme.

```
+ (void)navigateToLocation:(CLLocation*)_navLocation {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=driving",_navLocation.coordinate.latitude,_navLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
    } else {
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?ll=%f,%f",_navLocation.coordinate.latitude,_navLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Opens the maps and centers location on the lat, but doesn't start the navigation :(

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, Google and Apple both require the user input - but only to hit the go button.

If you want to specify both the start and end location, use the following format:

Apple Maps:

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=<Your Location>
```

Google Maps:

```
comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=&daddr=<Your Location>
```

Comment: be careful with placing %20 in the string, as % should be %% or use the space whatsoever

Comment: For Google Maps, the URL parameter nav=1 should start the navigation.  Still searching for a way to do it with Apple Maps.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 helper class for starting Apple Maps or Google Maps navigation

```
 struct LinksHelper {
    static func startNavigation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        struct Links {
            static let kGoogleMapsSchema = "comgooglemaps://"
            static let kGoogleMaps = "\(kGoogleMapsSchema)?daddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=driving"
            static let kAppleMaps = "https://maps.apple.com/?saddr=Current Location&daddr=%f,%f&z=10&t=s"
        }

        var path: String!

        if let googleMapsSchemaUrl = URL(string:Links.kGoogleMapsSchema), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(googleMapsSchemaUrl) {
            path = Links.kGoogleMaps
        } else {
            path = Links.kAppleMaps
        }
        guard let str = String(format: path, coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude).addingPercentEncoding(
            withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {
                return
        }

        guard let url = URL(string: str) else {
            return
        }

        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```